# .Net Application references another .Net Application in same .sln, referenced App's .exe.config not being copied over?

Tags: .net, deployment

One console application in a .net solution references another console application in the same solution but when building the first one, the second/referenced one's secondapp.exe.config file is not being deployed over.. does anyone know why or how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds kind of normal. If by 'referencing' you mean reference as an assembly, only the binary output is copied. You are not referencing the .config, and if you copy it manually it won't be used.

You will have to copy the relevant sections from the referenced config to the main one.

Of course, if you want to run the other app, it becomes a different story.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that, too. Not sure why it's been setup this way but I'll change deployment a little and everything should be fine.. Thanks Henk!